# IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputValueCallback fails if device plugged in since boot

Tags: macos, cocoa, usb, hid, iokit

I'm trying to communicate with a game controller using IOKit, in particular I want to be notified of value changes using `IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputValueCallback`.  My code works, except in the case that the device has been plugged in since the Mac was booted up and never unplugged.  In that case, `IOHIDDeviceOpen` still succeeds, but the value callback is never called.  And if I try to get values using `IOHIDDeviceGetValue`, it reports no error, but the integer values I get are all zero, which is incorrect.

If I unplug the device and plug it back it, the program starts getting value callbacks.

Is there anything I can do to fix this, or should I just blame hardware?

Maybe there's some way to do an unplug-and-replug in software.  The Kernel Framework Reference lists a function `ReEnumerateDevice` that sounds like it would do that, but I'd need a lot of help on how to use that, if it's even possible from non-kernel code.

```m
static void ValueCallback(
    void *context, 
    IOReturn result, 
    void *sender, 
    IOHIDValueRef value )
{
    IOHIDElementRef theElement = IOHIDValueGetElement( value );
    uint32_t usagePage = IOHIDElementGetUsagePage( theElement );
    uint32_t usage = IOHIDElementGetUsage( theElement );
    IOHIDElementCookie cookie = IOHIDElementGetCookie( theElement );
    IOHIDElementType typeCode = IOHIDElementGetType( theElement );

    CFIndex intValue = IOHIDValueGetIntegerValue( value );
    double physValue = IOHIDValueGetScaledValue( value,
        kIOHIDValueScaleTypePhysical );
    double calibratedValue = IOHIDValueGetScaledValue( value,
        kIOHIDValueScaleTypeCalibrated );

    NSLog(@"Element %@ (0x%X, 0x%X, %p, type %d) changed to %d (%f, %f)",
        theElement, (int)usagePage, (int)usage, cookie, (int) typeCode,
        (int)intValue, physValue, calibratedValue );
}

static void DeviceMatchingCallback(
    void *context,
    IOReturn result, 
    void *sender, 
    IOHIDDeviceRef device )
{
    NSLog( @"Added device %@", device );
    IOHIDDeviceScheduleWithRunLoop( device, CFRunLoopGetMain(),
        kCFRunLoopDefaultMode );
    IOReturn err = IOHIDDeviceOpen( device, kIOHIDOptionsTypeNone );
    NSLog(@"IOHIDDeviceOpen result 0x%08X", err );
    IOHIDDeviceRegisterInputValueCallback( device, ValueCallback, context );

    // Let's see if I can get elements and values.
    CFArrayRef elementArray = IOHIDDeviceCopyMatchingElements( device,
        NULL, 0 );
    if ( elementArray != NULL )
    {
        NSArray* elArray = (NSArray*)elementArray;
        for (id oneEl in elArray)
        {
            IOHIDElementRef anElement = (IOHIDElementRef) oneEl;
            IOHIDElementType elType = IOHIDElementGetType( anElement );
            NSLog(@"Element type %d", (int)elType);
            if ( (elType == 1) || (elType == 2) || (elType == 3) )
            {
                IOHIDElementCookie theCookie =
                    IOHIDElementGetCookie( anElement );
                CFIndex val = -1;
                IOHIDValueRef valueRef = NULL;
                err = IOHIDDeviceGetValue( device, anElement, &valueRef );
                if (err == kIOReturnSuccess)
                {
                    val = IOHIDValueGetIntegerValue( valueRef );
                    NSLog(@"  cookie %p, value %ld", theCookie, val );
                }
                else
                {
                    NSLog(@"  cookie %p, error getting value 0x%08X",
                        theCookie, err );
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

static void DeviceRemovalCallback(
    void *context, 
    IOReturn result, 
    void *sender, 
    IOHIDDeviceRef device )
{
    NSLog( @"Removed device %@", device );
    IOHIDDeviceUnscheduleFromRunLoop( device, CFRunLoopGetMain(),
        kCFRunLoopDefaultMode );
}

@implementation AppDelegate

@synthesize window = _window;

- (void)dealloc
{
    if (_hidManager != NULL)
    {
        CFRelease( _hidManager );
    }

    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    _hidManager = IOHIDManagerCreate( NULL, 0 );

    IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatchingMultiple( _hidManager, (CFArrayRef) @[
        @{ @(kIOHIDDeviceUsagePageKey): @(kHIDPage_GenericDesktop),
            @(kIOHIDDeviceUsageKey): @(kHIDUsage_GD_Joystick)
        },
        @{ @(kIOHIDDeviceUsagePageKey): @(kHIDPage_GenericDesktop),
            @(kIOHIDDeviceUsageKey): @(kHIDUsage_GD_GamePad)
        }
        ] );

    IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceMatchingCallback( _hidManager,
        DeviceMatchingCallback, self );
    IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceRemovalCallback( _hidManager,
        DeviceRemovalCallback, self );

    IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop( _hidManager, CFRunLoopGetMain(),
        kCFRunLoopDefaultMode );
}

@end
```

Comment: Does this affect all game controllers you've tried, or just some? Have you taken a look in IORegistryExplorer to see if another client has maybe taken control of the HID device? I can try your code when I get a chance in the next few days. If I can repro the issue I might be able to figure out a solution for you.

Comment: @pmdj, looks like it is just one model.  As for whether another client has taken control, how would I tell?  In IORegistryExplorer, under the entry for the game controller, I see two instance of IOHIDLibUserClient, one coming from my test app and one coming from loginwindow.

Comment: Do the devices that are not affected by the issue present in the same way in IOregistryExplorer?

Comment: @pmdj, they look pretty much the same to me in IORegistryExplorer, though I'm not sure what I'm looking for.  I took screen shots: [good one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/b58h0p5habaf9wp/ok%20controller%20ioregistry.png?dl=0) and [bad one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/txikoslxaqhosir/problem%20controller%20ioregistry.png?dl=0)

Answer (score -1):

It look like the OS during the boot will automatically unload the device (because unused)

---

When you disconnect ( and plug it again) the device, the OS will load the device...

---

From [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/IOKitFundamentals/Features/Features.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP0000012-BBCIGIID) , according to *Command-line tools used in driver development*, you may use:

```
kextload
```

> Loads a kernel extension (such as device driver) or generates a
>   statically linked symbol file for remote debugging.

and

```
kextunload
```

> Unloads a kernel extension (if possible).

---

Another thing that may help you:

> Driver Loading
>
> After all drivers have probed the device, the one with the highest probe score is attached and its startfunction, which must be implemented by all drivers, is invoked. The start function initializes the device hardware and prepares it for operation. If the driver succeeds in starting, it returns true; the remaining candidate driver instances are discarded and the driver that started successfully continues operating. **If the driver cannot initialize the hardware it must leave the hardware in the state it was in when start was invoked and return false.** The failing driver is then detached and discarded, and the candidate driver with the next highest probe score is given a chance to start.
>
> Some time after this occurs, **all loaded drivers that are not currently in use are unloaded.**

And to conclude [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeviceDrivers/Conceptual/AccessingHardware/AH_Intro/AH_Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000376) could also be helpful for you